# Not able to get value of parameterized variable in jenkins by perl

Tags: jenkins

I'm not able to get the value of parameterized variable in `jenkins` using `perl` , I am using ex. `$GIT_BRANCH=$ENV{"Git_Branch"};` but no value is passed to the `$GIT_BRANCH` variable.

Comment: Does `echo $ENV{"Git_Branch"}` return anything?

Comment: Choice : Name:Git_Branch
 option-1 OM16CDev
 option-2 OM16ADev
---------------------------------
$GIT_BRANCH=$ENV{"Git_Branch"};

print "$GIT_BRANCH"; # nothing printing here                           

if($GIT_BRANCH eq "OM16CDev")
 {
  $delivery="OM16C";
 }

Comment: This way i am trying to catch the value to but passing to the variable. Please help

Comment: I mean no return any value - it a perl script.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by using:

```
$GIT_BRANCH=$ENV{"GIT_BRANCH"};
```

instead of:

```
$GIT_BRANCH=$ENV{"Git_Branch"};
```